# How to read words from sys.stdin and filter the ones ending in "iary"

Tags: python

My current attempt is:

```
iary_word = [word for word in sys.stdin if word.endswith("iary")
print(len(iary_word))
```

but it always prints 0.

What is wrong with my code and how can I make it work?

Comment: You should clarify what exactly is wrong with your current code. If you get an error, always include the complete error traceback. If you don't get the expected output, include a well chosen sample input, and the corresponding output vs expected output.

Comment: it just prints 0 instead of the expected value which is 14 in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iterating on `sys.stdin`, just as when iterating on a text file object, Python iterates line by line.

So, you get a line, not a single word, in each iteration of your for loop. You have to split this line to get individual words:

```
iary_words = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    for word in line.split():
        if word.endswith('iary'):
            iary_words.append(word)
```

Or with a list comprehension, nesting the loops in the same order:

```
iary_words = [word for line in sys.stdin for word in line.split() if word.endswith('iary')]
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, when you take input from `sys.stdin`, you didn't strip the newline character. The newline character (`\n`) is added to the end of each input from `sys.stdin`. This will ruin the list, as the words taken end with `"iary\n"` instead of just `"iary"`.

So before you do *anything*, you might want to do a `.rstrip()` before the check in the iteration, something like this:

```py
iary_words = []

for line in sys.stdin:

   sentence = line.rstrip('\n') 
   # this turns something like "biary\n" to "biary"

   if sentence.endswith("iary"):

      iary_words.append(sentence)

return len(iary_words)
```

This *works*, but it's not the shining definition of beauty. Maybe you can list comprehension this, but this was just easier.